# QueryDSL joins generate invalid SQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query in QueryDSL (JPA, Hibernate provider, Oracle database):

```
select c.id
      , c.name
      , count(coalesce(s.company_id_source, t.company_id_target))
  from company              c
  left join company_mapping s on(s.company_id_source = c.id)
  left join company_mapping t on(t.company_id_target = c.id)
 group 
    by c.id
      ,c.name;
```

My java code:

```
QCompany company = new QCompany("company");
QCompanyMapping companyMappingSource = new QCompanyMapping("companymappingS");
QCompanyMapping companyMappingTarget = new QCompanyMapping("companymappingT");
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query = query.from(company)
query = query.leftJoin(company.companyMappingsForCompanyIdSource, companyMappingSource);
query = query.leftJoin(company.companyMappingsForCompanyIdTarget, companyMappingTarget);
List<Expression<?>> outPaths = new ArrayList<Expression<?>>();
// add c.id and c.name to outPaths - omitted
outPaths.add(companyMappingSource.companyByCompanyIdSource.count().add(companyMappingTarget.companyByCompanyIdTarget.count()));
// add the group by clause - omitted
List<Object[]> rows = query.listDistinct( outPaths.toArray(new Expression<?>[0]));
```

It compiles fine but I get a runtime Exception

> ORA-00904: "COMPANY0_"."ID": invalid identifier

This is the query generated according to the Hibernate log output:

```
select distinct company0_.ID as col_0_0_, company0_.NAME as col_1_0_, 
count(companymap1_.COMPANY_ID_SOURCE)+count(companymap2_.COMPANY_ID_TARGET) as col_2_0_
from COMPANY company0_ 
left outer join COMPANY_MAPPING companymap1_ on company0_.ID=companymap1_.COMPANY_ID_SOURCE
, COMPANY company3_
left outer join COMPANY_MAPPING companymap2_ on company0_.ID=companymap2_.COMPANY_ID_TARGET
, COMPANY company4_ 
where companymap1_.COMPANY_ID_SOURCE=company3_.ID and companymap2_.COMPANY_ID_TARGET=company4_.ID 
group by company0_.ID , company0_.NAME
```

If I run this query by hand in Oracle I get the same error. I don't understand where the two useless joins with company (company3_ and company4_) come from and the whole where clause. If I remove these sections it works in Oracle again.

Calling toString() on the query obj outputs

```
select company
from Company company
  left join company.companyMappingsForCompanyIdSource as companymappingS
  left join company.companyMappingsForCompanyIdTarget as companymappingT
where upper(company.name) like ?1 escape '!'
group by company.id, company.name
```

The QCompanyMapping class is defined as

```
public class QCompanyMapping extends EntityPathBase<CompanyMapping> {
// ..
    public final QCompany companyByCompanyIdSource;

    public final QCompany companyByCompanyIdTarget;
// ..
}
```

**Possible alternative solution?**
There's an alternative equivalent SQL query that seems to be even more elegant and might translate correctly throught Hibernate:

```
select c.id
,      c.name
,      count(cm.id)
from   company c
left join company_mapping cm on c.id in (cm.company_id_source, cm.company_id_target)
group by c.id, c.name
```

However I don't know how to express it in QueryDSL.

Comment: Could you provide the JPQL query that is generated by Querydsl? The error seems to happen in the JPQL -> SQL phase, which is handled by Hibernate

Comment: You mean by calling toString() on query? I added the output to my edited question.

Comment: I am not sure what fails, company0_.ID usage looks ok, btw which Querydsl version, also why the like predicate in JPQL, but not in SQL and Querydsl?

Comment: I use the QueryDSL version 2.9.0. I added the LIKE criterium in the meantime but I also tried it without. I'm attaching the relevant lines from QCompanyMapping class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change

1. "companyMappingSource.companyByCompanyIdSource.count()" to "companyMappingSource.count()"
2. "companyMappingTarget.companyByCompanyIdTarget.count()" to "companyMappingTarget.count()"

in your java code for first query then it works:

```
outPaths.add(companyMappingSource.count().add(companyMappingTarget.count()));
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! The generated query looks perfect, the two useless joins are gone!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the aliased paths after the joins.

These might trigger additional joins

```
outPaths.add(QCompanyMapping.companyMapping.companyByCompanyIdSource.count().add(
         QCompanyMapping.companyMapping.companyByCompanyIdTarget.count()));
```

Comment: I changed it to outPaths.add(companyMappingSource.companyByCompanyIdSource.count().add(companyMappingTarget.companyByCompanyIdTarget.count())) and edited my original question but the error remains